# What is the "monetization_status" of video in Facebook api and when to use it?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

What is the "monetization_status" of video in Facebook api and when to use it?

I am looking for any documentation about this field and the only page I found is this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video, saying that this field is the "enum" type, no possible values, nor when to use it.

The point is that I get "ineligible" for videos that I have monetized before, and I wonder what does it mean, and how can I get status "eligible"?

Thanks

Comment: Do you just have this issue with specific videos, or is the account used not eligible any more in general? In the latter case, you have to submit for appeal, https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/151371415454526 // https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/monetizationstandards has more hints on what criteria you have to fulfill and what guidelines need to be followed.

Comment: I see now, I didn't know about the submitting for appeal.
Thank you